# using sl4j to log from an eclipse osgi plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, osgi, slf4j

I'm using sl4j from my eclipse (luna) osgi bundles. Everything was working fine until I upgraded to eclipse mars.
I broke something, somewhere and I can't figure out what I did wrong.

After a few hours trying to put everything back, I decide to write a simple osgi bundle to test the mecanism that, *i thought*, I understood.

I'm going through the new osgi wizard and create this simple bundle:

The manifest is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Service
Bundle-SymbolicName: service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: service.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
 org.slf4j
Require-Bundle: ch.qos.logback.classic,
 ch.qos.logback.core
```

and the Activator code is:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
private Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello World!!");
    logger.error("logging error {}", this);
}

public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Goodbye World!!");
}
```

}

and I put a logback.xml configuration file next to the Activator.java.

but I keep running into the well known message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hello World!!
```

when i run the bundle as an OSGI Framework debug target.

I checked that url, previous posts on stackexchange and other web sites, but I can't see what's wrong.

I know it has to be a such simple glitch that I can't see it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Christian: Thanks, your answer lead me to the solution wich is 
the ch.qos.logback.slf4j bundle seems to be missing **missing** from the Eclipse Mars default Distribution.

After configuring Eclipse to use the Orbit http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20151221205849/ P2 repository (in the Edit Target preferences) , the missing bundle could be added and my test is now sucessful.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the Require-Bundle for logback as your bundle does not depend on logback directly. At runtime you have to make sure that logback is installed and that slf4j-api is NOT installed.

Also see [this post](https://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/osgi-logging-part-7-configure-your-logging-framework-the-dynamic-way/) for how to configure logback in OSGi.

Comment: org.slf4j.api is required by both ch.qos.logback.classic and ch.qos.logback.core so I must include it in the list of bundles to launch with mine in order to prevent a Missing Constraint.

Comment: You are right. I only checked for pax-logging which I am more familiar with. There you do not need the slf4j-api at runtime. For logback you need it.